# How to display an expression the way it was entered?

Tags: python, sympy, jupyter-lab

Consider this SymPy expression:

```py
import sympy as sp
n, k = sp.symbols("n, k")
sp.summation((n - k) * 2 * k, (k, 1, n - 1))
```

When I enter it in JupyterLab and display it, already a simplification is shown to me:

[image: 1]

However, this time I'd like to view it exactly as I've entered it (but with the nice rendering) – e.g. to check for typos. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Sum`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html#sympy.concrete.summations.Sum) will skip the summation related simplifications (but note the internal ones are a different issue):

[image]

As the above linked documentation states, `Represents unevaluated summation.`

Comment: The mention of `Sum`, and within the reference also the mention of `Product`, is useful in this specific case. But is there a general way of just showing the bare input expression, independent of its type?

Comment: @user3389669 many of sympy's core classes perform simplification upon creation. I'm not sure there is a simple way to actually disable all of them